# Include guards for modules

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

This may be a ridiculous question and I'm 99% sure of the answer but I wanted to be sure.

> `C++20` `modules` do ***not*** require any type of include guards for `module` interface files.

Is my statement correct? Everything I've read about modules thus far leads me to believe that guards are not required as modules are only ever compiled once and then reused for each translation unit that imports that module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include guards are not needed. Modules are only imported once.

Preprocessor defines do not escape from modules, so include guards would not work anyway.

> [Macros, preprocessor directives, and non-exported names declared in a module are not visible and therefore have no effect on the compilation of the translation unit that imports the module.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick response. Once the accept timer has elapsed I'll accept your answer.